# In the graphic novel DuRaRaRa!!! what does the name mean?

Tags: durarara

What is the meaning of DuRaRaRa!!! I was told it was a reference to a word meaning non-sense but, I can't find that anywhere. So, what does it really mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Trivia/Durarara), it doesn't mean anything and is just gibberish that the author (Ryohgo Narita) made up on the spot:

> When asked by his editor for a title, the auhor [sic] had none in mind and spouted a few random syllables.

Narita explained this in [a blog post in 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20150111155001/http://differentclouds.livejournal.com/16825.html) (credit to @merlyn for finding this):

> ...I was editing the finished draft of the book and my editor called and asked, “Isn’t it time to give an official title to the Public Relations department?”
>
> So I just randomly gave a name, “Du…Durarara?”
>
> [...]
>
> Thus the title ‘Durarara!!’ was born—although to this day I’m still not quite sure what it’s supposed to mean.

Comment: Wikipedia links to Durarara volume 1 afterword where Narita talks about it: https://web.archive.org/web/20150111155001/http://differentclouds.livejournal.com/16825.html